# custom view pager :Error inflating class android.support.v4.app.ViewPager

Tags: android

hi i want to make custom viewpager, in that i am loading 2 images in each viewpage

my java code is below

This is the mainactivity.java

```
   public class MainActivity extends Activity {

ViewPager viewPager;
int img1[] = { R.drawable.ic_launcher, R.drawable.ic_launcher,
        R.drawable.ic_launcher, R.drawable.ic_launcher };

int img2[] = { R.drawable.ic_launcher, R.drawable.ic_launcher,
        R.drawable.ic_launcher, R.drawable.ic_launcher };

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    viewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.viewPager);

    viewPager
            .setAdapter(new ViewPagerAdapter(MainActivity.this, img1, img2));
}
```

}

now ViewPagerAdapter class

```
 public class ViewPagerAdapter extends PagerAdapter {

Context context;
int[] img1;
int[] img2;

LayoutInflater inflater;

public ViewPagerAdapter(Context context, int[] img1, int[] img2) {
    this.context = context;
    this.img1 = img1;
    this.img2 = img2;
}

@Override
public boolean isViewFromObject(View view, Object object) {
    return view == ((RelativeLayout) object);
}

@Override
public Object instantiateItem(ViewGroup container, int position) {

    inflater = (LayoutInflater) context
            .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    View itemView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.pager_item, container, false);

    // define resources of corresponding image views here.
    // finally bind images to the imageviews.

    ((ViewPager) container).addView(itemView);

    return itemView;
}

@Override
public void destroyItem(ViewGroup container, int position, Object object) {
    ((ViewPager) container).removeView((LinearLayout) object);

}

@Override
public int getCount() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return img1.length;
}

@Override
public void startUpdate(ViewGroup container) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.startUpdate(container);

}

}
```

the activity_main.xml is

```
<android.support.v4.app.ViewPager
    android:id="@+id/viewPager"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:text="@string/hello_world" />
```

but everytime i am getting an error like

```
     Binary XML file line #11: Error inflating class android.support.v4.app.ViewPager
```

the logcat is below

```
     01-09 11:29:31.853: E/AndroidRuntime(22506): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.viewpagerdemo/com.example.viewpagerdemo.MainActivity}:      android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #11: Error inflating class android.support.v4.app.ViewPager
01-09 11:29:31.853: E/AndroidRuntime(22506):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2343)
01-09 11:29:31.853: E/AndroidRuntime(22506):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2395)
01-09 11:29:31.853: E/AndroidRuntime(22506):    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:162)
01-09 11:29:31.853: E/AndroidRuntime(22506):    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1364)
01-09 11:29:31.853: E/AndroidRuntime(22506):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:107)
01-09 11:29:31.853: E/AndroidRuntime(22506):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:194)
01-09 11:29:31.853: E/AndroidRuntime(22506):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5371)
01-09 11:29:31.853: E/AndroidRuntime(22506):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
01-09 11:29:31.853: E/AndroidRuntime(22506):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:525)
01-09 11:29:31.853: E/AndroidRuntime(22506):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:833)
01-09 11:29:31.853: E/AndroidRuntime(22506):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:600)
01-09 11:29:31.853: E/AndroidRuntime(22506):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
01-09 11:29:31.853: E/AndroidRuntime(22506): Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #11: Error inflating class android.support.v4.app.ViewPager
01-09 11:29:31.853: E/AndroidRuntime(22506):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:698)
01-09 11:29:31.853: E/AndroidRuntime(22506):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:746)
01-09 11:29:31.853: E/AndroidRuntime(22506):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:489)
01-09 11:29:31.853: E/AndroidRuntime(22506):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:396)
01-09 11:29:31.853: E/AndroidRuntime(22506):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:352)
01-09 11:29:31.853: E/AndroidRuntime(22506):    at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.setContentView(PhoneWindow.java:281)
01-09 11:29:31.853: E/AndroidRuntime(22506):    at android.app.Activity.setContentView(Activity.java:1881)
01-09 11:29:31.853: E/AndroidRuntime(22506):    at com.example.viewpagerdemo.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:20)
01-09 11:29:31.853: E/AndroidRuntime(22506):    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5122)
01-09 11:29:31.853: E/AndroidRuntime(22506):    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1081)
01-09 11:29:31.853: E/AndroidRuntime(22506):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2307)
01-09 11:29:31.853: E/AndroidRuntime(22506):    ... 11 more
01-09 11:29:31.853: E/AndroidRuntime(22506): Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "android.support.v4.app.ViewPager" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/com.example.viewpagerdemo-1.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app-lib/com.example.viewpagerdemo-1, /vendor/lib, /system/lib]]
01-09 11:29:31.853: E/AndroidRuntime(22506):    at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(BaseDexClassLoader.java:53)
01-09 11:29:31.853: E/AndroidRuntime(22506):    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:501)
01-09 11:29:31.853: E/AndroidRuntime(22506):    at   java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:461)
01-09 11:29:31.853: E/AndroidRuntime(22506):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:552)
01-09 11:29:31.853: E/AndroidRuntime(22506):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:687)
01-09 11:29:31.853: E/AndroidRuntime(22506):    ... 21 more
```

Comment: Have you added the Support library of `ViewPager` in your project ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

it should be

```
      <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
```

instead of

```
      <android.support.v4.app.ViewPager
```

Answer (score 0):

[image]You need to check libraries into Order and Export tab under Project->Properties->Java Build Path

Comment: i have done the same way as you have describe but still not working

Comment: clean the project and run